# Laravel custom Admin-Filter with redirect-loop

Tags: php, laravel, admin

I got a dumb question here. I've a endless redirect in my app. I understand why, but don't know what to do to solve this issue.

In my routes.php I've the following code:

```
Route::filter('admin', function(){
    if(Auth::user()->admin){
        return Redirect::to(Route::current()->getPath());
    }else{
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
Route::when('admin/*', 'admin');
```

When I call the url `/admin/createNews` the browser is loading for a while and tell me that there is a redirect. For me this is logical but I don't know what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your filter passes, execution flow will continue to the originally requested route, without the need to `return Redirect`. So the solution is to just reverse your logic:

```
Route::filter('admin', function() 
{
    if( !(Auth::user()->admin) ) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

Comment: Awww... dammit. That works... i thought the Filter would need any action there.
Thanks bro!